# C++ read file until char found

Tags: c++, file

I want to create a function that can read a file char by char continuously until some specific char encountered.

This is my method in a class FileHandler.

```
char* tysort::FileHandler::readUntilCharFound(size_t start, char seek)
{
    char* text = new char;

    if(this->inputFileStream != nullptr)
    {
        bool goOn = true;

        size_t seekPos = start;

        while (goOn)
        {
            this->inputFileStream->seekg(seekPos);

            char* buffer = new char;

            this->inputFileStream->read(buffer, 1);

            if(strcmp(buffer, &seek) != 0)
            {
                strcat(text, buffer); // Execution stops here

                seekPos++;
            }
            else
            {
                goOn = false;
            }
        }
    }

    //printf("%s\n", text);

    return text;
}
```

I test this function and it actually works. This is an example to read a file content until new line character `'\n'` found.

```
size_t startPosition = 0;
char* text = this->fileHandler->readUntilCharFound(startPosition, '\n');
```

However, I am sure that something not right is exists somewhere in the code because if I use those method in a loop block, the app will just hangs. I guess the 'not right' things are about pointer but I don't know exactly where. Could you please point out for me?

Comment: Allocating `char`'s chunkwise with `new` will turn out to be extremely inefficient, and unnecessarily memory consuming.

Comment: So how can I allocate a character array without knowing its length if I'm not using `new`?

Comment: You never `delete` the memory pointed to by `buffer` resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: @yunhasnawa You should use something like `std::string` and `std:::getline()` instead, so you'll not need to wrap your head around memory management. Also for reading `char` wise use something like `char c; inputFileStream->get(c);`

Comment: You should read a little more about pointers. What's the point in having this function returning a `char*`? Do you want a null-terminated string with one character? In that case, you must allocate `new char[2]`. On the other hand, what's the point in that? simply return a `char` from this function and use it in the calling function. As to the problem you're experiencing - function `strcat` expects a null-terminated string as the second parameter. Clearly `buffer` is not null-terminated, hence you've got a big problem. In addition, `text` is not large enough to accommodate 2 or more `char`s.

Comment: If you really want to accumulate chars one by one in a buffer, you could use a `std::vector<char>`, and copy its content once you're done with your scan.

Comment: Would [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) or [`std::basic_istream::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) not work?

Comment: However, since you can *seek* in your file stream, it would probably be much better to simply keep track of the starting point of the scan, and extract the whole `char[]` in one go when you've found its length.

Comment: At any rate, this `strcat` on a single char must be avoided (you allocate 1 char with `new`, technically, it is a `char*`, but strcat *will not* expand that space for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines

```
        if(strcmp(buffer, &seek) != 0)
```

and

```
            strcat(text, buffer); // Execution stops here
```

are causes for undefined behavior. `strcmp` and `strcat` expect null terminated strings.

Here's an updated version, with appropriate comments.

```
char* tysort::FileHandler::readUntilCharFound(size_t start, char seek)
{
   // If you want to return a string containing 
   // one character, you have to allocate at least two characters.
   // The first one contains the character you want to return.
   // The second one contains the null character - '\0'
   char* text = new char[2];

   // Make it a null terminated string.
   text[1] = '\0';

   if(this->inputFileStream != nullptr)
   {
      bool goOn = true;

      size_t seekPos = start;

      while (goOn)
      {
         this->inputFileStream->seekg(seekPos);

         // No need to allocate memory form the heap.
         char buffer[2];

         this->inputFileStream->read(buffer, 1);
         if( buffer[0] == seek )
         {
            buffer[1] = '\0';
            strcat(text, buffer);

            seekPos++;
         }
         else
         {
            goOn = false;
         }
      }
   }

   return text;
}
```

You can further simplify the function to:

```
char* tysort::FileHandler::readUntilCharFound(size_t start, char seek)
{
   // If you want to return a string containing 
   // one character, you have to allocate at least two characters.
   // The first one contains the character you want to return.
   // The second one contains the null character - '\0'
   char* text = new char[2];
   text[1] = '\0';

   if(this->inputFileStream != nullptr)
   {
      this->inputFileStream->seekg(start);

      // Keep reading from the stream until we find the character
      // we are looking for or EOF is reached.
      int c;
      while ( (c = this->inputFileStream->get()) != EOF && c != seek )
      {
      }

      if ( c != EOF )
      {
         text[0] = c;
      }
   }

   return text;
}
```

Comment: Despite a little change in `if( buffer[0] == seek )`, the code works and did give me a lot of sight for more understanding in the concept of pointer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

C++ provides some easy-to-use solutions. For instance:

```
istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);
```

In your case, the parameter would be the equivalent of your `text` variable and delim would be the equivalent of your `seek` parameter. Also, the return value of getline would in some way be the equivalent of your `goOn` flag (there are good FAQs regarding the right patterns to check for EOF and IO errors using the return value of getline)

Answer (score 0):

```
        this->inputFileStream->read(buffer, 1);
```

No error checking.

```
        if(strcmp(buffer, &seek) != 0)
```

The `strcmp` function is used to compare *strings*. Here you just want to compare two characters.